# make giving error after make clean

Tags: gcc, makefile, dependencies, gnu-make

Although Make is working fine but by default it only compiling those files that have been changed, even when I run `make all`. It say like `Nothing to Do`.

One scenario where I neeed to compile all the files is when I change something in a header file which is being accessed in multiple `.c` files. But make does not recognize it until I open any `.c` file any `save & quit` again.

Makefile contents can be seen in this post :

[Questions about Makefile - what is "$+" & where are .c files/dependencies called here ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431581/questions-about-makefile-what-is-where-are-c-files-dependencies-called)

Although this is also a problem but actual problem I want to discuss here is something different.

In order to compile all files what I did was that I ran `make clean` which indeed removed all object files and then I ran `make` again but this time it gives an error :-

```
 ....
 mec/gen_crc32table > mec/crc32table.h
 mec/gen_crc32table: 1: mec/gen_crc32table: Syntax error: end of file unexpected    
 (expecting ")")
 make: *** [mec/crc32table.h] Error 2
```

I checked contents of `crc32table.h` but file is empty. So, I copy `crc32table.h` from my backup of previous code and now its running successfully. Now I run `make clean` and 'make' again to check it but this time it is working fine.

I do not know what the mystery here ?

I guess these lines are doing something which I am not able to understand ? Please help me on this.

```
crc32.o: mec/crc32table.h mec/crc32.c
$(CC) -o $@ -c -I. $(CFLAGS) mec/crc32.c

mec/crc32table.h: mec/gen_crc32table
mec/gen_crc32table > mec/crc32table.h
```

Comment: Automatic dependency handling (e.g. knowing that `foo.o` must be rebuilt when `bar.h` has been changed) is an advanced topic; you should learn the basics better before you attempt it. As for the second problem, there is something wrong with `mec/gen_crc32table`; show us what it is, and maybe we can help.

Comment: @Beta `mec/gen_crc32table` seems like an object file by looking at the contents. There is one more file `mec/gen_crc32table.c`. May be it have been generated by compiling it,I can only gave this much info based on my understanding as I am not the actual owner, I am just modifying the code for my purpose but my actual doubt is what this `>` doing ? Tranfering contents of an object file to an header file. It makes no sense for me.

Comment: The rule tries to *execute* `gen_crc32table` and store the output in the file `crc32table.h`. If you don't understand these tools and can't consult the author, you shouldn't be using them. This is not something we can *fix*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this snippet:

```
mec/crc32table.h: mec/gen_crc32table
    mec/gen_crc32table > mec/crc32table.h
```

Ask yourself "What happens if the `gen_crc32table` command exits with an error?" Make stops (good) but leaves behind a corrupt `crc32table.h` (bad). Two choices: (i) re-write `gen_crc32table` so that it accepts a `-o` parameter; (ii) shell trickery.

(i)

```
mec/crc32table.h: mec/gen_crc32table
    mec/gen_crc32table -o mec/crc32table.h
```

(ii)

```
mec/crc32table.h: mec/gen_crc32table
    mec/gen_crc32table >temp-file-with-an-obscure-name
    mv temp-file-with-an-obscure-name $@
```

The `mv` will not happen if `gen_crc32table` errors.